# iOS: Keep view centered on screen during rotation

Tags: ios, rotation

If you look at the default alert view, when presented, it stays in exactly the same location during device rotation. It appears to rotate from its own center.

I've made a custom alert view and would like the same behavior. I have a container view which includes a background view (to dim out the screen some) and the alert view. When I rotate, the alert view jumps to what will be the new center after the rotation, then animates into place. How can I get it to rotate from its own center?

Comment: You can use the [willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration] delegate method and then in  [UIView animateWithDuration:duration:animations:] you can swap the alert's center x & y values around. Just set the duration value to the willRotate's duration parameter and it will animate smoothly while the rotation animates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is merely that your constraints positioning the alert view are incorrect. If they are correct, centering will happen automatically and will remain in place during rotation.

For example:

```
v.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleTopMargin | .FlexibleBottomMargin | .FlexibleLeftMargin | .FlexibleRightMargin
v.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
```

Comment: Take a look at my downloadable example project here: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7 It shows how to make a thing that looks like an alert view. It darkens the background, just like an alert, and stays centered on rotation, just like an alert. Feel free to steal this code!

Comment: Holy ****, you're right. That just worked. I was using constraints so I never would have thought it was an autoresizingMask issue. Thanks!

Comment: @matt I've been searching around on and off for hours trying to fix this problem. Your answer works great!!! I just looked at your profile and your the author for Programming iOS 10. I have this book, it's extremely in depth. You're a rockstar :)

Comment: @LanceSamaria Thanks. And see the github example (referenced in my earlier comment) for more detail.

Comment: @matt I looked at it. I'm going to go through it this week 

Answer (score 1):

Here is Matt's solution in Swift 2+ syntax:

```
v.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleTopMargin , .FlexibleBottomMargin , .FlexibleLeftMargin , .FlexibleRightMargin]
v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```